# Concatenate two dataframes by two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I need to concatenate 2 pandas DataFrames by 2 colunms.
Example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3],'col2':[11,22,33]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'col2':[11,22,33,44,55,66],'col3':[111,222,333,444,555,666]})

df2
    col1  col2  col3
       1    11   111
       2    22   222
       3    33   333
       4    44   444
       5    55   555
       6    66   666

df1
col1  col2
   1    11
   2    22
   3    33
```

Result:

```
col1  col2   col3 
   1    11    111
   2    22    222
   3    33    333
```

Here `col1` and `col2` used as index for values form `df2.col3`.
Thanks. 
(Sorry, my English is bad)

Comment: pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.merge`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3],'col2':[11,22,33]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'col2':[11,22,33,44,55,66],'col3':[111,222,333,444,555,666]})

print( df2.merge(df1, on=["col1", "col2"]) )
```

**Output:**

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     1    11   111
1     2    22   222
2     3    33   333
```